# Taking a Derivative of a Random Variable

Tags: probability

I have a function that is a comination of a random and determinisitic variables.

$$
f(w)=100*(1+fw)
$$

Where $w(p)={1, p>.5, -1, p<=.5}$ Where $p$ is a uniform random variable between $[0,1]$. What I want to know is what is the optimal $f$ that maximizes the value of this function?

I want to take the derivavtive of this function but I don't know how to do so if the function is stochastic with a random variable that is Bernoulli.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. To begin with: what is the expression $fw$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $f$ is a real number. It's the value I am trying to maximize. $w$ is the random variable.

Answer (score 1):

You mean $ 100*(1+f(w(p))) $ ? Derivative of a random function would be correspondingly random. The constant drops off anyway on differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is *linear* so I don't see how it can have a maximum or minimum.

Perhaps you mean $f(k,w) = 100 \times(1 + k w)$ where $\mathbb{P}[w = 1] = \mathbb{P}[w=-1]=0.5$

Notice that $\mathbb{E}f(k,w) = 100$ since $\mathbb{E}[w] = 0$ even though $w = \pm 1$ always.

In general $f(k,w) = 100 \pm k$.  In fact $\mathbb{P}[f = 100 + k] = \mathbb{P}[f = 100 - k]  = 0.5$